# How to stop python program from executing twice after asking admin privileges in windows

Tags: python, windows, admin, privileges

I have a program that needs admin privileges to function.

```
import ctypes, sys
from threading import Thread

def firstThread():
    #something about UI

def secondThread():
    def is_admin():
        try:
            return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
        except:
            return False

    
    if is_admin():
       #code functionality
    else:
        # Re-run the program with admin rights
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     firstThread()
     codeFunctionality = Thread(target=secondThread)
     codeFunctionality.start()
```

The problem is that it runs in two threads, the one that needs admin privileges runs second to the first thread. So, when it's time to ask for admin privileges, `firstThread` has already executed and the UI is displayed. After asking for admin privileges, the program restarts, and `firstThread` is called again, resulting in two UI's being displayed on the desktop

Comment: So, why don't you, when the program detects it needs to run again, close the UI created by the `firstThread()`?

Comment:  Wow, windows surprises every time anew.

The first thing that comes to mind is to create a file and write there the time let's say... Then treat it as follows: if the time from the file is less than couple of seconds ago, do nothing;

Or delete the file the second time it's accessed and remove it (like a flip-flop)

Comment: @quamrana The problem is that the privileges for `firstThread` and `secondThread` are not connected. When `secondThread` has gained admin priv, `firstThread` still hasn't. There's no way for `firstThread` to know if `secondThread` has gained admin privs

Comment: Well, yes, of course, but `secondThread` knows. You could pass in a reference to the UI from `firstThread` into `secondThread` and now there is a route for that information to get back the the UI.

Comment: @quamrana I'm wrapping my head around this trying to implement your solution. I tried to add a global variable that changes once it gets admin privs. But the program runs a different instance, so the global variable that I added was basically useless. Can you elaborate what you mean by pass in a reference please?

Comment: My assumption is that when you first run the program, it doesn't have admin privileges, but you can detect that and run a completely new instance which *does* have admin.  Well, I've just had a thought. Why not make the first program just stop. That will take down the UI as well. Surely when the admin version runs, at some point you stop the program. Just make the first program stop.

Comment: @quamrana I'm also thinking of another solution. Is there a way to make the program or command that needs admin privileges exempt from always asking it? Like, it could only ask for admin privileges during installation. When the program is now exempt, it always run as admin and therefore wouldn't need to rerun the program. Is there a way to do it?